# Stuck on this limit: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} ln\frac{n-2}{n+3}\arctan\frac{e^{2n}}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I've tried applying the Stirling's formula $n! \tilde ~n^n\cdot e^{-n}\sqrt{2πn}$ and obtain 0 as the result of the second term of the limit, as well as for the first, is it correct? Wolfram Alpha not even solve it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tink if you work as follows, you will get the answer better:

when $\alpha(x)$ is very small, then $\ln(1-\alpha(x))\sim\alpha(x)$ so $$\ln\left(\frac{n-2}{n+3}\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac{-5}{n+3}\right)\sim \frac{-5}{n+3}$$

and when $\alpha(x)$ is very small, then $\tan^{-1}(\alpha(x))\sim\alpha(x)$ so $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\text{e}^{2n}}{n!}\right)\sim \frac{\text{e}^{2n}}{n!}$$ because $\frac{\text{e}^{2n}}{n!}$ is so small when $n\to\infty.$